# Can we expect support for mutually left recursive rules in ANTLR 4.8 or 5?

Tags: antlr4

Can we expect support for mutually left recursive rules in ANTLR 4.8 or 5? It seems like it is so hard to write rules without this feature. The direct left recursion rules get so big and there is no way to break it down into individual parser rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 4.8 is already out w/o support for that and I very much doubt there will be support for indirect left recursion in any future version of ANTLR.